# Backup bash script and tar exclude logs and directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup

Following script takes the backup of all websites which are in directory /var/www/websites and create .tar.gz for each individual website at /var/backup and works fine

```
WEBROOT="/var/www/websites"
BAKPATH="/var/backup"

for vhost in "$WEBROOT"/*; do
  test -d "$vhost" || continue
  base=$(basename "$vhost")
  ( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -cpzf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base" )
done
```

But, I need to exclude logs folder and one website from backup, like we normally exclude with tar as

> --exclude=$BAKPATH/*/logs or --exclude=$BAKPATH/website2.com

I am not sure where to put that in? I tried following but it does not work

```
WEBROOT="/var/www/websites"
BAKPATH="/var/backup"

for vhost in "$WEBROOT"/*; do
  test -d "$vhost" || continue
  base=$(basename "$vhost")
  ( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -cpzf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz --exclude=$BAKPATH/*/logs --exclude=$BAKPATH/website2.com" "$base")
done
```

Where should I put

> --exclude=$BAKPATH/*/logs --exclude=$BAKPATH/website2.com

so it take affect?

Comment: Why `$BAKPATH`?  Shouldn't it be sth like `"$vhost/*/logs"` instead?  Mind also, that this is to be given as a *pattern*, so you'll have to quote the usage of the asterisk.

Comment: @rkta yes, I tried to do but that did not work like

`( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -cpzf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base" --exclude=$BAKPATH/*/logs --exclude=$BAKPATH/website2.com)`

Comment: @Alfe where do you want me to do this? like this: `base=$(basename "$vhost/*/logs")` also how to exclude multiple directories?

Comment: The way I see it, you're doing tar for each individual site within $WEBROOT. First I would verify that $vhost is not website2.com and not bother to do the tar at all. Second, the log file you're trying to exclude should be $vhost/logs (no star).

Comment: @rkta No, I just tried this but did not work it is still taking backup of everything
`( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar --exclude=$BAKPATH/*/logs --exclude=$BAKPATH/website2.com -cpzf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base")`

Comment: @AndreGelinas logs are under website, so BAKPATH/*/logs is correct.

Comment: @Farmi, if the logs are under website then it's WEBROOT/*/logs no ? ... and WEBROOT/* is really $vhost within the for loop. My understanding of --exclude is that you exclude from the source, not the destination.

Comment: @AndreGelinas yes, I tried that too but did not work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some feedback from different sources, I was able to achieve this by adding following lines with if condition

```
##ADD THIS
  if [[ $vhost = *"website1.com"* || $vhost = *"website2.co.uk"* ]]; then
  continue
  fi
##
```

So, finally the script looks like this

```
WEBROOT="/var/www/websites"
BAKPATH="/var/backup"

for vhost in "$WEBROOT"/*; do
  test -d "$vhost" || continue
  if [[ $vhost = *"website1.com"* || $vhost = *"website2.co.uk"* ]]; then
  continue
  fi
  base=$(basename "$vhost")
  ( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -cpzf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base" )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`$BAKPATH` is the place where the *target* of the backup process (the archive, the *.tgz file) is supposed to be created.  If you want to exclude something from the *source*, you have to specify the paths in the *source*:

```
tar -cpz --exclude "$base/logs" \
    -f "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base"
```

This will exclude all files which match the glob pattern `$base/logs` (and everything below).

According to your question, I assume that you want to exclude e. g. a file named `/var/www/websites/cardboardwebshop/logs/access.log`.  If this is not correct, please comment, maybe we can figure out what exactly you need to write to exclude what you want to exclude.

Comment: I want to exclude the complete `/var/www/websites/website1.com/logs` directory from all websites, and one website itself as well which is website2.com

I tried following but it fails too `( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -cpzf --exclude "$base/*/logs" --exclude "$base/website1.com" \ -f "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base")`